# What is the difference between KBD and XKB?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

The [KDB Project](https://kbd-project.org/) and the [XKB](https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/) both handle the keyboard and keymaps?

Why they both have files for Keyboard Layouts (KDB with .map files and XKB with the Symbols folder)?

What exactly each project do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do the exact same thing. But different on how they do it and what is required from user to configure them.

Why there are two of them? That is easy: there are many more than just two... [iBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus), [fcitx](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Fcitx_5), [xim](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19504-01/802-7789/6ibcsnfb6/index.html) That is just most famous and usable.

The **XKB** was first, it is nice and works fine, but has lots of limitations. **XIM** was an attempt to rectify the problem of working with non-alhphabetical languages. Not exactly successful, so **iBus** was invented.

Then *some* people thought that alphabet-based language is enough, but **XKB** is not very convenient to use, so they made **KBD**. Same happens with **iBus** and **fcitx**. More or less successful attempts to do the same but in a better way.

Nowadays it is more a mater of taste and habit. Majority people use **XKB** since it comes as default in majority of distributions. If a person feels adventurous or require a custom layout and tired of fighting with **XKB** - such person uses **KBD**. Same for languages like Japanese or Chinese but with **iBus** vs **Fcitx**.

Comment: So why XKB and KBD are both installed in my system?

Comment: Because they are not drivers and therefore not exclusive. The actual keyboard is managed by kernel. The xkb and kbd are just set of maps and tools to manage those maps between logical keys (A, B, C, F1, F2, Home, Backspace, etc) and scancodes which comes from a hardware keyboard. Kernel's driver is getting a scancode, pass it to IM filter, it converts scancode to logical key and sends it to active application.